# How to export contentVersion using sfdx force:data:tree:export

Tags: apex, salesforcedx, contentversion

I am looking for a way to prepopulate my scratch org with some sample data. As part of this sample data, I need to also create few content version records(images).

But the `sfdx force:data:tree:export` command returns version data as a link.

I also tried to store serialized version of contentversion records and insert them on new scratch org creation but it fails because of inconsistency in how apex serializes and deserializes base64 data.

Is there a recommended approach to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce CLI has limited support for the file unless you use a custom script it.

Looks like community has a solution,

Install the `shane-sfdx-plugins` using `sfdx plugins:install shane-sfdx-plugins`

Once installed I would explore the below commands

```
sfdx shane:data:file:download -i <filed>
```

And upload using

```
sfdx shane:data:file:upload -f <filepath> -p <parentId>
```

You can explore Shane's amazing work [here](https://github.com/mshanemc/shane-sfdx-plugins).